# Change alignment inline in QTextEdit

Tags: pyqt, qt5, qtextedit

I'm trying to align one piece of text inline to the left and one piece of line of text to the right in a `QTextEdit`. The only example I've found demonstrating how to do this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855024/aligning-text-in-qtextedit).

However, that question appends the new text every time, which effectively creates a new block. I need to do the formatting inline, so that one piece of text is left-justified, and one piece of text is right-justified.

Is there any way to do this? I looked into using tables, but it looked like the tables had a universal alignment setting.

Comment: If you mean two pieces of text in a single line, one piece left and another piece on the right end, that is not something  you can achieve trivially. You may have to subclass `QTextBlock` and implemment the mehod yourself.

Comment: @Marcus, that's a bummer. Any advice on subclassing QTextBlock?